# Leaflet overlay does not appear, but no Javascript Console errors

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am new to Leaflet. Right now, I am trying to incorporate an overlay into a Google map using Leaflet 1.3.1.

Here is the html code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.5.0/dist/esri-leaflet.js"
integrity="sha512-ucw7Grpc+iEQZa711gcjgMBnmd9qju1CICsRaryvX7HJklK0pGl/prxKvtHwpgm5ZHdvAil7YPxI1oWPOWK3UQ=="
crossorigin=""></script>
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
   var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
  zoomControl: false

  });


 L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
    url: "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/haz/hazfaults2014/",
opacity: 1,
}).addTo(mymap);
```

There are no console errors but nothing is showing up and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Probably the url does not work. [this](https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Specialty/Soil_Survey_Map/MapServer) works

Answer (score 0):

So I ended needing to use a tiled map layer on that url rather than a dynamic map layer. Thanks!